# Getting Lucene search score field from the Hit object in the Sitecore

Tags: lucene, sitecore

In the sitecore, I'm using Lucene search in the following way:

```
IndexSearchContext context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext(); 
SearchHits hits = context.Search(searchString); 
var results = hits.FetchResults(0, hits.Length);
```

How can I get the score field value from the hits?

Comment: What version are you using? Sitecore 7?

Answer (score 1):

In Sitecore 7, you can use this code:

```cs
var queryable = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where([LAMBDA QUERY]);
var results = query.GetResults();

foreach (SearchHit<SearchResultItem> result in results.Hits)
{
   var score = result.Score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int hitsCounnt = hits.length();
for (int i = 0; i < hitsCounnt ; i++)
{
  float hitScore = hits.score(i);

}
```

Please try above code. It should work for you.